# Rewriting Try + Catch{System.Assert(false, 'blahblah')} for easy toggle-off of catch?

Tags: apex, error-messages, try-catch, stacktrace

Dear Salesforce StackExchange,

An outside partner set a precedent in some of our Apex triggers of doing major operations *(such as DML)* inside a `try`/`catch` block, and having the `catch` block simply contain a `System.Assert(false, 'Blah blah blah failed');` statement inside it.

I like this because something feels right about not propagating deep stack traces up to a user in production code.  Like teaching your kids to say you're busy, rather than not home, when they answer the phone to a stranger.

That said, if I get an error with production data and want to see what lies below the `'Blah blah blah failed'` message, it's a royal pain to wait 20 minutes for validation tests to pass so I can replace the try-catch with a simple call to whatever was in the `try` block ***(to allow deeper errors to bubble up to me)***.

Does anyone have any efficient, secure, portable suggestions to improve this kind of code so I can simply "flip a switch" in the org and let the code know, "Someone's looking deeply at errors - let them bubble up"?

Specifically ... where in the Salesforce org would you recommend I put the "switch?"

Comment: Never use `system.assert(false)` in production code.

Comment: @AdrianLarson, thanks for the input, but can you elaborate why not?

Comment: They are designed to be used in tests. Also the resulting exception cannot be caught.

Comment: the dan appleman advanced apex 3rd edition has a useful pattern for recording diagnostic data  that may be useful to you

Comment: So @AdrianLarson, you don't see any value in the "teaching your kids to lie and say you're busy" (generic error instead of full-depth error) approach to exception-message propagation under normal circumstances?

Comment: I'm with @AdrianLarson here -- bubbling up the error is always helpful. It lets you diagnose quicker and, if the error happens a lot, indicates some missing validations or other problems with the code that should be fixed.  If the code hits a limit exception or worse, a 'gack', sfdc doesn't hide that from the user, so, by inference, an error in your app's internal logic shouldn't be hidden either

Comment: @AdrianLarson, thanks for editing my post - I hadn't noticed the "inline code" feature and will use it lovingly from now on!  crop1645, too - you two have been very helpful; many thanks.

Comment: @k.. They are magic. You'll fit right in here.

Comment: @k.. Is this still an open question? Marking an answer as accepted will make it clear you have resolved your issue. :) Not sure if you have though!

Comment: @AdrianLarson - sure.  I was waiting to see if anything else came along, but it hasn't, and I definitely value your assistance!  :-)

Comment: @k.. Makes a lot of sense. Getting enough attention for old posts can be pretty tough on SFSE. Once you have more rep, bounties start to make more sense as a strategy to do so.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at [An Introduction to Exception Handling](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/An_Introduction_to_Exception_Handling).

For the record, I think there are better approaches to error handling than hiding the root cause. Personally, I would rather see `Duplicate Value` or `Close Date must be in the future` instead of `Something went wrong`.

If you want to maintain the existing pattern, you should use the `SObject.addError` method. Using `system.assert(false)` means that every dml operation is all or none, making it impossible to retain partially successful saves.

You can use a `Hierarchy Custom Setting` to toggle this behavior, with the advantage that you have granular control at the `Profile` or even `User` level. For example you can just make it so `Hide DML` is always `false` for `System Administrators`.

```
if (ExceptionHandling__c.getOrgDefaults().Hide_Dml__c)
{
    insert newRecords;
}
else
{
    insertAndHideExceptions(newRecords);
}
```

With the masking method looking something like:

```
try
{
    insert newRecords;
}
catch (DmlException dmx)
{
    for (Integer i = 0; i < dmx.getNumDml(); i++)
    {
        Integer index = dmx.getDmlIndex(i);
        newRecords[index].addError(SOME_GENERIC_MESSAGE);
    }
}
```